# Order of an element in an external direct product

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Consider

$\mathbb{Z}_{4}\times \mathbb{Z}_{4}=\left \{ 0,1,2,3 \right \}\times \left \{ 0,1,2,3 \right \}$

The element $\left ( 2,0 \right )$ is of order 2 but I cannot figure out why.

$2=LCM\left ( \left | 2 \right |,\left | 0 \right | \right )=LCM\left ( 2.2Mod4,0Mod4 \right )=LCM\left ( 2,0 \right )$

But $LCM\left ( 2,0 \right ) is....0$

Some clarification please? Thanks in advance

Comment: $(2,0)+(2,0) = (0,0) = e$.

Comment: The order of $0$, the identity element of $\mathbb Z_4$, is not $0$. It's $1$. The order of the identity element is always $1$, not $0$.

Comment: There is no element of order $0$, by definition of [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_%28group_theory%29).

Comment: Thank clears the air! Thanks people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(2,0)+(2,0)=(0,0)$ which is the identity.
Thus it's order is 2.

Another example: the order of $(1,1)$ is 4.